# Psychic Corrosion and Day's Undoing

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Can someone explain to me how the triggered ability of [Psychic Corrosion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bPsychic%20Corrosion%5d) would interact with [Day's Undoing](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDay%27s%5d%2b%5bUndoing%5d)?

From what I understand of the stack, the triggered abilities go on the stack after each card draw due to Day's Undoing is triggered, so opponents discard two cards at each draw immediately before further effects of Day's Undoing happen, then the Day's Undoing "exile all effects on the stack" comes into play afterwards. However, I admit that it could be interpreted in a different way. Do I grossly misunderstand?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Day's Undoing will prevent Psychic Corrosion from doing anything.  (Your opponents will not have to mill 14 cards.)

Although Day's Undoing has multiple effects, the card represents a single Spell when played<sup>[111.1](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Spell)</sup>, and all of its effects must be resolved before anything else on the Stack is evaluated<sup>[608.2c](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Resolving_spells_and_abilities)</sup>.  Psychic Corrosion's ability will be triggered 7 times, but the abilities would not go onto the stack until *after* Day's Undoing has finished resolving<sup>[603.3](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability)</sup>.  However, because Day's Undoing ends the turn immediately upon resolution, those triggers never make it onto the stack.

Gatherer has a ruling for Day's Undoing that clarifies this explicitly:

> If any abilities trigger while players are shuffling cards into their library or drawing seven cards, those abilities cease to exist when the turn ends. They won’t be put on the stack.

Comment: The Psychic Corrosion triggered abilities will not go on the stack, because the process of putting them on the stack only happens after the spell finishes resolving.

Comment: @murgatroid99 You're correct, of course. :)  I've edited to correct my wording.

Comment: It might be worth editing to avoid saying "discard" (or really, to avoid implying that the opponents would have to discard if not for the ending of the turn) because Psychic Corrosion never makes anyone discard any cards, it only mills.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you cast the spell on your turn, the triggers would go on the stack, then get exiled as the spell resolves because of how the stack works. Here's a rundown:

1. You cast Day's Undoing and it resolves.
2. Each player shuffles and draws, creating 7 delayed Psychic Corrosion triggers. These triggers are delayed because Day's Undoing is still resolving.
3. The turn ends, exiling all the triggers on the stack.

Now, if you cast the spell on your opponent's turn somehow, the delayed triggers will go off after the spell resolves.

Comment: "Delayed trigger" has a specific rules meaning that does not match how you are using the term. The abilities are just triggering.

Comment: CR 603.7: An effect may create a delayed triggered ability that can do something at a later time. A delayed triggered ability will contain “when,” “whenever,” or “at,” although that word won’t usually begin the ability.

Psychic Corrosion: Whenever you draw a card, each opponent puts the top two cards of their library into their graveyard.

Creating the triggers happens when the action happens, but not resolving them until later is the chapter and verse definition of a delayed trigger. Arguing the semantics of 603.7 vs "a trigger that happens later" is needlessly obfuscating the issue.

Comment: This is not an effect creating a triggered ability. It is just a triggered ability that exists on a permanent.

Comment: CR 603.7a is talking about exactly this. "Delayed triggered abilities are created during the resolution of spells or other abilities, as the result of a replacement effect being applied, or as a result of a static ability that allows a player to take an action"

Comment: The ability in question is not being created by anything. It is simply a characteristic of a permanent. All triggered abilities have "when", "whenever", or "at", and all triggered abilities resolve after they trigger, with a priority cycle in between. That does not make them all delayed triggers. Delayed triggers are specifically ephemeral abilities that **trigger** after the effect that creates them. [Arcbond](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=391793) is a good example of an effect creating a delayed triggered ability.

Comment: So now, wait a minute: if I were to play Day's Undoing on someone else's turn (say, via Mission Briefing), I'd be able to gain the discard triggers?

Comment: Day's Undoing only ends the turn if it's your turn.